# How do I list only children of a specific category in a drop-down?

Tags: categories

Okay, I think I'm pretty close. I have the following going on:

```
$cat_id = get_cat_id('library');

wp_dropdown_categories('hierarchical=1&parent=$cat_id');
```

However, it doesn't work with $cat_id in there. It does work when I put the category's ID number in there (which I got when I echoed $cat_id), but obviously that presents a problem when I install the site on the real server. What should I try? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your single quote marks in to double quote marks  it should work :

```
$cat_id = get_cat_id('library');
wp_dropdown_categories("hierarchical=1&parent=$cat_id");
```

but if you really want to make it more flexible you can phrase your arguments as an array:

```
$args = array(
 'hierarchical' => 1,
 'parent' => get_cat_id('library'));
wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

and if you want to make it even more flexible to get the current category's children you can use `get_query_var('cat');` assuming that you are in your category.php file, so:

```
$args = array(
 'hierarchical' => 1,
 'parent' => get_query_var('cat'));
wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

Comment: The PHP manual has more info about [the difference between single and double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Basically it boils down to the fact that a `$` in a single quoted string will not indicate a variable, so your `$cat_id` stays `$cat_id`, not `11` or whatever the category ID might be.

Comment: Doh! I can't believe I forgot to concatenate that variable. No wonder I felt like it's worked before. Thank you very much for answering my dumb question. Also, I didn't know about the double-quote trick before.